# How can I configure my Android tablet to output sound to a remote Pulseaudio instance?

Tags: software-recommendation, pulseaudio, android

I have a Transformer TF101 tablet with Ubuntu One music on it.

The speakers are good enough, but I have an Ubuntu computer hooked up to my nice stereo in my living room. I'd like to be able to just walk around my apartment with the tablet controlling my music, but have the sound stream going from my network to my Ubuntu PC.

I know how to configure Pulseaudio to do this from Linux-to-Linux machines, however I am not sure how the tablet fits into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed not as easy a task to perform, at least not as easy as having another pulseaudio server runnning on android (which to my knowledge is not possible).

We may have two options:

1. Run a streaming app such as [VLC direct](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vlcdirect.vlcdirect&feature=more_from_developer) on the Android device
2. Run a remote application to control your music player that runs on the Ubuntu box

   - [Remuco](http://code.google.com/p/remuco/)
   - [Tesla](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/android-tesla/)

Considering the net congestion from audio streams, and the somewhat limited CPU power of a tablet PC I'd propably go for the Remote apps. Bote remote apps need an MPRIS capapble music player for operation. However then you may not have access to the music stored on the tablet.